# json posts in micropython

Tags: json, post, python-requests, micropython

I use the code below in python on a rpi to do json posts

```
import requests
payload = '{"msg_type":"observation_payload","msg": 
{"serial":"FZtank","observations":{"8":{"d":0,"m":"JSON upload 
test","t":"1543540780"}}}}'
r = requests.post('https://my.website/api/observations', data = 
{'post_wrapper':payload})
print r.text
```

it produces

```
{"msg": {"remote_pi": "FZtank", "stored_ids": ["8"]}, "msg_type": "receipt"}
```

I figured it wouldn't be too hard to do the same thing in micropython on a pycom device

```
import urequests as requests
payload = '{"msg_type":"observation_payload","msg": 
{"serial":"FZtank","observations":{"8":{"d":0,"m":"JSON upload 
test","t":"1543540780"}}}}'
r = requests.post('https://my.website/api/observations', data = 
{"post_wrapper":payload})
print(r.text)
r.close()
```

but it gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
File "/flash/lib/urequests.py", line 115, in post
File "/flash/lib/urequests.py", line 100, in request
File "/flash/lib/urequests.py", line 79, in request
TypeError: object with buffer protocol required
```

The TypeError msg means it wants a string instead of a dictionary for the data

so I tried

```
import urequests as requests
payload = '{"post_wrapper":{"msg_type":"observation_payload","msg": 
{"serial":"FZtank","observations":{"8":{"d":0,"m":"JSON upload 
test","t":"1543540780"}}}}}'
r = requests.post('https://my.website/api/observations', data =payload)
print(r.text)
r.close()
```

but that gives

```
{"msg": {"errorText": "Malformed POST - unable to decode JSON"}, "msg_type": 
"error"}
```

So now I'm confused. Is the problem that the website expects a dictionary & micropython can only send a string?

.

Some further detail:
I'm using https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/urequests/urequests.py but with line 52 changed from ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, usocket.SOCK_STREAM) to ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port) because it used to throw an error msg about 4 arguments Vs 2. If I run

```
import urequests as requests
payload = '{"post_wrapper":{"msg_type":"observation_payload","msg": 
{"serial":"FZtank","observations":{"8":{"d":0,"m":"JSON upload 
test","t":"1543540780"}}}}}'
r = requests.post('https://my.website/api/observations', data=payload)
```

or

```
import urequests as requests
payload = {"post_wrapper":{"msg_type":"observation_payload","msg": 
{"serial":"FZtank","observations":{"8":{"d":0,"m":"JSON upload 
test","t":"1543540780"}}}}}
r = requests.post('https://my.website/api/observations', json=payload)
```

or

```
import urequests as requests
payload = {"msg_type":"observation_payload","msg": 
{"serial":"FZtank","observations":{"8":{"d":0,"m":"JSON upload 
test","t":"1543540780"}}}}
r = requests.post('https://my.website/api/observations', json= 
{"post_wrapper":payload})
```

I get the same result

```
{"msg": {"errorText": "Malformed POST - unable to decode JSON"}, "msg_type": 
"error"}
```

Comment: *The TypeError msg means it wants a string* not so sure about that, it says it wants an object with a buffer protocol. That might be a string, but there are likely other objects supporting that as well. Looking at the source code at https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/urequests/urequests.py seems to indicate you can just pass `json={'post_wrapper': payload}` though?

Comment: I tried that but it says TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. I feel I got close with ujson.dumps but it bleats about library line 51 port=int(port) saying OSError: 128

Comment: I fail to see how changing any argument other than `url` can effect the port; are you sure that's not a seperate unrelated issue? Also maybe post full error messages including line numbers, that's much easier to get help for.

Comment: OK I expanded the original post some more

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck with the same issue here while trying to send push notifications through pushed.co.

I was using `data=payload` on urequests and getting this `TypeError: object with buffer protocol required` error. All worked well when I changed to `json=payload` following @stijn suggestion on his answer.

Steps I did:

1. on micropython REPL install urequests

```py
import upip
upip.install('micropython-urequests')
```

2. for my example the code is

```py
import urequests as requests
payload = {
    "app_key": "your_app_key",
    "app_secret": "your_app_secret",
    "target_type": "your_target_type",
    "content": "Hello from micropython",
}
r = requests.post("https://api.pushed.co/1/push", json=payload)
```

Probably any other url will do fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make posts request on micropython dumping data into a json:

```py
import json
import urequests
data = {"mykey": 'myvalue'}
urequests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
```